# PHP PDO rowCount returns -1 on SELECT statement

Tags: php, pdo, ms-access-2007, rowcount

I am having a strange problem that has been kicking my backside all day long.

I have the following code:

```
$today = date("m/d/Y");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE is_errata = 0 AND kill_date >= '$today' AND msg_date <= '$today' ORDER BY msg_date";
$ps = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if (!$ps) {
    echo "PDO::errorInfo():";
    print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
}else{
    $ps->execute();
    $number_of_rows = $ps->rowCount();
```

When I display the value of $number_of_rows, it ALWAYS displays -1, even when I get results.

Anyone else have this problem?

Oh, and the database I am using is NOT MySQL, but the lovely MS Access. I suspect this might be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowCount()` method does NOT return number of rows from `SELECT` statement. It's common mistake.

> **PDOStatement::rowCount()** returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding
>   PDOStatement object.
>   If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, **this behaviour is not guaranteed**
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

More details you can find in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

So to get number of rows you have to write `SELECT` statement with sql `COUNT(*)` function. In your case:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM msgs WHERE is_errata = 0 AND kill_date >= '$today' AND msg_date <= '$today' ORDER BY msg_date";
```

or using PHP:

```
$number_of_rows = count($ps->fetchAll());
```

You should also learn to prepare the query the right way

Comment: I can't iterate with 'foreach' after this. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score -1):

You should use `iterator_count` to count rows, i.e.

```
$number_of_rows = iterator_count($ps);
```